# Need to detect if lock screen is enabled from windows command line

Tags: windows, security, lockscreen

I would like to create a quick batch script to be executed on all windows 10/11 computer in my office, just for a quick system check.
In our rules lock screen is mandatory but sometimes someone decide to disable it. The purpose of the script I'd like to make is to detect also this case.

How can I do it? Should I search for a specific registry entry?